# Can I create a configuration page for a Teams bot app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm building my first Teams app which will have two primary functions:

1. Proactively send a message to the channel (the bot is installed into) when a specific event occurs on my backend.
2. Members of the channel reacts to the message via actions.

I finally have a pretty good idea of how to set this up (I think) - but one part I'm missing is that in order to identify the specific app installation as belonging to one of my customers, I need to be able to allow the installing user to supply extra information like e.g. an API-key so that I can associate the specific channel with my specific customer.

Is there any way of doing this with a bot app? I've found examples for creating a configuration page, but they all seem to be associated with tab apps?
I could of cource have the bot ask the user for the information - but maybe there's a "cleaner" way?

Any examples or tutorials would be greatly appreciated as I find it rather hard to get stuff working using Microsoft's own examples etc. :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT but does this also apply to a bot apps? I've come across that article before, but it seems to me that it only covers tabs? Or would you simply install both a bot and a tab when adding your app? (e.g. adding a tab for the channel you install the app into)
Sorry if this is a total newbie question - but I am litterally a Teams app newbie - and I'm having a bit of a hard time with the documentation regarding real-life scenarios / best practices :) 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your app contains both bot and tab capabilities, then you install the app, it will add both.

Comment: Thanks @Prasad-MSFT - I'll give it a go and see if I can't figure it out :) 
Is it considered bad practice to have the bot itself ask the user for a key upon installation (via Adaptive Cards) and then replacing the message with a response message upon submitting? 
If I can't get the tab functionality working then that might be a solution for me to go the other route. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive any message from the user, either by typing to your bot, or even installing it into a channel, group chat, or personal context (where you get the conversationUpdate event), you are able to get specific details off of the `activity` object. If the user sends a message, for instance, then the `text` property on the `activity` object will have a value. Incidentally, this is the same `activity` you will use to get the conversation details you need for the Proactive message.

With regards your question, the `activity` class also includes a `tenantId` property, hanging off the `conversation` property. This is the unique Microsoft 365 Id for the tenant, which would be what I'd suggest to uniquely identify them for your API, or licensing, or similar.

Comment: I'm already storing the TenantId. My problem is that I need an active value from the user in order to allow them to access other API's in my backend (which aren't hooked up with AD or MS Identity). 
But I actually got the proactive messaging working - so I'll investigate @Prasad-MSFT comment above.
If all else fails, I figure I can make a bot installation flow where the bot asks for a key upon installation. 
Thanks for the feedback. I'll update as soon as I get something working! :)